# Print javascript's method name in IDEA live template

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

In IDEA there is live template `soutm` which prints method name in Java files.

Can I define such live template for javascript and typescript files in IDEA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `jsClassName()` and `jsMethodName()` built-in functions for this:

[image]

Comment: Yes. That's what I need. Thank you!